# What does the title of Charlie Stross's "Halting State" refer to?

Tags: books, charles-stross

Someone I know recently enrolled in an introductory computer science course that introduced her to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). She also recently read Charles Stross's book *[Halting State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_State)*, and was curious if that particular title referred to the halting problem.

Does anyone know if that's true, or if not, what "Halting State" refers to?

Comment: Given that the author is a CS major/ex-programmer, and that the sequel is called "Rule 34", I wouldn't rule out that there's a reference. But so far after 10 mins of intense research couldn't find any proof.

Comment: BTW, I emailed the author. Let's see if he chooses to disclose the info.

Comment: From memory (it's been a few years), the notion mentioned in the title does come up. Not the halting problem (which is the problem of determining whether a program halts), but a halting state of a [finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton): a state in which the automaton has done its job and stops looking.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have emailed the author, and while he declined to join the site at the moment, he was gracious enough to provide the answer to be posted:

> It was a pun; both a reference to the halting problem, and a nod to the main plot of the book (an attempt to bring a small European state to a screeching halt). Yes, this is public.

Comment: Charlie does participate on many online sites.  I often see him jump into the fray on Metafilter.